# order igraph vertexes

Tags: r, igraph

data frame t

```
Student         Played     Count
Mike            Soccer          5
Mike            Football        10
Mike            Golf            15
Mike            Hockey          2
```

need to create an igraph where I need to show Student in the center and Played as vertex's. I can do this by the following:

```
g <- graph.data.frame(t)
plot(g, layout = layout.kamada.kawai,  vertex.label = V(g)$name,  vertex.label.color= "darkblue",  edge.arrow.size=0.9,  edge.curved=T, edge.label=t$count, edge.label.color="#F900F9", edge.label.font=10,vertex.shape="rectangle",edge.color="darkgreen")
```

This works but I like to order the graph by the count. For example, vertexes for Played should be order counter-clock wise by the count. In this case Hockey should be first than, soccer etc. Can anybody help me with that? This way it would be better readable by the end user. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this easily with `layout.star`, please check the manual and tell me if you cannot work it out.